# Convergence of Value Iteration in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am struggling to understand when the value iteration algorithm converge.

Suppose that I use a discount 1.

Will the algorithm always converge if I have terminal states in the MDP or it has to do on how I define the rewards?

I understand that if I have terminal states in the MDP the MDP is episodic. So will end sometime. So, do I have to use a discount smaller than 1 to converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few requirements for Value Iteration to guarantee convergence:

- State space and action space should be finite
- Reward values should have an upper and lower bound
- Environment should be episodic or *if continuous* then discount factor should be less than 1
- The value function should be represented as a table, one entry per state. If you use function approximation over state vectors, then value iteration can be unstable, just like Q Learning.

> I understand that if I have terminal states in the MDP the MDP is episodic. So will end sometime.

That is not necessarily a strong enough guarantee. If there are loops in state possible, where an agent could either get stuck gaining negative rewards, or where it could gain infinite positive reward over time, then you may have a problem with episodes not ending.

> So, do I have to use a discount smaller than 1 to converge?

For a strictly episodic problem - no opt-in loops with positive reward, no "trap" loops with negative reward - then no. Discounting is not required in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your time. 

If I understand it correctly, if I use a discount equal to 1 for an episodic task then the way the rewards are defined plays an important role for the convergence of the value iteration in order to avoid "trap" loops etc. 
Is that correct?

One more question. If I have a strictly episodic problem and choose to formulate the terminal state as absorbing state then the MDP is converted to continuous and I should use a discount less than one? I believe that the algorithm will converge even with a discount 1.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. If you have a strictly episodic problem, then both with or without absorbing terminal states you can use a discount of 1. The maths is the same either way, the absorbing states are designed to not interfere with the values of any calculations.

Comment: Thanks. The MDP I have is one with 600 states and one terminal state  which I want to avoid. The empirical (estimated) rewards r(s,a,s')  are positive or zeros on all states (s') for every action except the terminal state which is negative.
So I believe I have an episodic task that is not strictly and if I use a discount equal to 1 the value iteration is going on forever because the agent chooses actions with probability = 1 that avoid the terminal state. So in order to converge I should use a discount<1 or define the rewards different or the p(s,a,s')<1 for the terminal state. Correct?

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the solution to my problem, The problem arises because for every state I have at least one action with positive reward which with probability = 1 avoids the terminal state (bad state negative reward). So, the agent always chooses that action and the value of the states approaches inf. I believe that is the problem.

Comment: @gnikol: In your case yes you will need a discount factor, because a successful agent may never terminate the episode.